# How to change values in a list using a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have been trying the sieve of eratosthenes algorithm by myself and I encountered this problem:

```
import math
n=int(input('Enter the number'))
b=list(range(2,n+1))
for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
    for j in b:
        if j!=i and j%i==0:
            print(j)
            b[b.index(j)]=0 #This line is my trouble!!! Why doesn't it work if it was j=0???
print(b)
```

I hope I was clear with the question. I'm welcome to any suggestions that are reasonably simple since I'm a beginner. If there's anything I'm doing wrong, please do point that out as well. Thank You

Comment: The values in `b` start from `2`. It doesn't contain `0`.

Comment: The code seems to work fine. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: My problem is-
            b[b.index(j)]=0 #This line is my trouble!!! Why doesn't it work if it was j=0??? @Nick

Comment: But `j` can never be 0 since it only takes values from `b` and `b` starts at 2...

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between b[b.index(j)]=0 and j=0 and why I am able to alter the list only using b[b.index(j)]=0? How does j behave in this code, what is the logic behind?@Nick